# WinForms DataGridView Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to figure out how to set a cell in a dataGridView to ReadOnly.
The checkbox is being added by the boolean property. Therefore, I looking for tips how to accomplished the task of setting a cell to readonly based on the column with the boolean property.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
[DisplayName("Lock")]
public bool RevenueLock { get; set; }

revenue = new DomesticCostRevenue()
{
RevenueLock = Convert.ToBoolean(values[10]),
Revenue = Convert.ToDouble(values[11])
};
domestic.Add(revenue);
}
CostRevenueGridView.DataSource = domestic;
```

This is what I've done but no success so far.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in CostRevenueGridView.Rows)
{
if ((bool)row.Cells["RevenueLock"].Value == true)
{
row.Cells["Revenue"].ReadOnly = true;

//MessageBox.Show("Lock");
}
}
```

Comment: You can set the whole column or the whole row or a specific cell read only

Comment: How? That is what I am trying to figure out. I just want a specific cell.

Comment: What's the problem with above code?

Comment: is not setting the "Revenue" cell to readonly.  When I add a breakpoint to that line of code, it says ReadOnly = true, but if I click on cell, i can still edit the cell.

Comment: Check if you made the correct cell readonly. Probably you made a cell readonly but you are trying to edit another cell?

Comment: No, whole row is editable

Comment: probably a "feature" from Microsoft?

Comment: I made a simple program and I can't reproduce the case. the ReadOnly works properly.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a simple code?

Comment: Still the same problem.  breakpoint displays cell is readonly but still editable.

Comment: I'll post an answer that share a simple code that shows the option works properly. Use the code in the post and confirm if it works properly.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: I'll let you know.  Left work, so I will be login in from home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the help.  I finally was able to solve my problem.  The below snippet is my solution.

```
    private void CostRevenueGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in CostRevenueGridView.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex == 12)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(CostRevenueGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value))
                    {
                        row.Cells[11].ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the whole column or the whole row or a specific cell read only:

- Column: `this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;`
- Row: `this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].ReadOnly = true;`
- Cell: `this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;`

**Test**

Put the below code in a button click or somewhere else to show a form to you. In first row, the second cell will be read only, because the first cell value is true:

```
var f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(new DataGridView
{
    Name = "g",
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
});
f.Load += (se, ev) =>
{
    var g = ((Form)se).Controls["g"] as DataGridView;
    g.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    g.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    g.DataSource = new List<C1>
    {
        new C1{P1=true, P2="x"},
        new C1{P1=false, P2="y"},
    };
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in g.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)row.Cells["P1"].Value == true)
            row.Cells["P2"].ReadOnly = true;
    }
};
f.ShowDialog();
```

And here is the code for class C1:

```
public class C1
{
    public bool P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

Also the problem doesn't exist with `DataTable`:

```
f.Load += (se, ev) =>
{
    var g = ((Form)se).Controls["g"] as DataGridView;
    g.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    g.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("P1", typeof(bool));
    dt.Columns.Add("P2", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(true, "x");
    dt.Rows.Add(false, "y");
    g.DataSource = dt;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in g.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)row.Cells["P1"].Value == true)
            row.Cells["P2"].ReadOnly = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is weird, breakpoint says readonly = true, but still editable

Comment: I have a CellValueChange event if users decides to click the checkbox, which it works perfectly.  But when setting a cell readonly from retrieving from database does not work.

Comment: Going to recheck my logic.  Your snippet looks similar to mine, but no success in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your issue by creating a `DataTable`, populating with two columns matching yours, and then using the `foreach` loop you posted. My results were the same as yours. The individual cells that were `ReadOnly` were still editable.

I'm not sure why this is, but since Reza got it to work with a `List<T>`, I assume it has something to do with a `DataTable`.

Try subscribing to the `RowsAdded` event, and moving your check into there. Column names may not work with this code... if not, use the column indexes instead.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int index = e.RowIndex; index <= e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1; index++)
    {
        var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[index];

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(currentRow.Cells[0].Value))
            currentRow.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried `DataTable` and it works properly. I shared the full code in the post. Probably you try to set the column readonly when there is no row in datagridview?

Comment: My grid has data. But it still behaving the same way.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my code snippet that domestic is a List.    List<T> domestic = new List<T>();